# Convert from clojure.lang.LazySeq to type org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD

Tags: java, clojure, apache-spark, clojure-java-interop, flambo

I developed a function in clojure to fill in an empty column from the last non-empty value, I'm assuming this works, given

```
(:require [flambo.api :as f])

(defn replicate-val
  [ rdd input ]
  (let [{:keys [ col ]} input
    result (reductions (fn [a b]
                         (if (empty? (nth b col))
                           (assoc b col (nth a col))
                           b)) rdd )]
(println "Result type is: "(type result))))
```

Got this:

```
;=> "Result type is:  clojure.lang.LazySeq"
```

The question is how do I convert this back to type JavaRDD, using flambo (spark wrapper)

I tried `(f/map result #(.toJavaRDD %))` in the `let` form to attempt to convert to `JavaRDD` type

I got this error

```
"No matching method found: map for class clojure.lang.LazySeq"
```

which is expected because result is of type `clojure.lang.LazySeq`

Question is how to I make this conversion, or how can I refactor the code to accomodate this.

Here is a sample input rdd:

```
(type rdd) ;=> "org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD"
```

But looks like:

```
[["04" "2" "3"] ["04" "" "5"] ["5" "16" ""] ["07" "" "36"] ["07" "" "34"] ["07" "25" "34"]]
```

Required output is:

```
[["04" "2" "3"] ["04" "2" "5"] ["5" "16" ""] ["07" "16" "36"] ["07" "16" "34"] ["07" "25" "34"]]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all RDDs are not iterable (don't implement `ISeq`) so you cannot use `reductions`. Ignoring that a whole idea of accessing previous record is rather tricky. First of all you cannot directly access values from an another partition. Moreover only transformations which don't require shuffling preserve order.

The simplest approach here would be to use Data Frames and Window functions with explicit order but as far as I know Flambo doesn't implement required methods. It is always possible to use raw SQL or access Java/Scala API but if you want to avoid this you can try following pipeline.

First lets create a broadcast variable with last values per partition:

```clj
(require '[flambo.broadcast :as bd])
(import org.apache.spark.TaskContext)

(def last-per-part (f/fn [it]
  (let [context (TaskContext/get) xs (iterator-seq it)]
  [[(.partitionId context) (last xs)]])))

(def last-vals-bd
 (bd/broadcast sc
   (into {} (-> rdd (f/map-partitions last-per-part) (f/collect)))))
```

Next some helper for the actual job:

```clj
(defn fill-pair [col]
  (fn [x] (let [[a b] x] (if (empty? (nth b col)) (assoc b col (nth a col)) b))))

(def fill-pairs
  (f/fn [it] (let [part-id (.partitionId (TaskContext/get)) ;; Get partion ID
                   xs (iterator-seq it) ;; Convert input to seq
                   prev (if (zero? part-id) ;; Find previous element
                     (first xs) ((bd/value last-vals-bd) part-id))        
                   ;; Create seq of pairs (prev, current)
                   pairs (partition 2 1 (cons prev xs))
                   ;; Same as before
                   {:keys [ col ]} input
                   ;; Prepare mapping function
                   mapper (fill-pair col)]
               (map mapper pairs))))
```

Finally you can use `fill-pairs` to `map-partitions`:

```clj
(-> rdd (f/map-partitions fill-pairs) (f/collect))
```

A hidden assumption here is that order of the partitions follows order of the values. It may or may not be in general case but without explicit ordering it is probably the best you can get.

Alternative approach is to `zipWithIndex`, swap order of values and perform join with offset.

```clj
(require '[flambo.tuple :as tp])

(def rdd-idx (f/map-to-pair (.zipWithIndex rdd) #(.swap %)))

(def rdd-idx-offset
  (f/map-to-pair rdd-idx
    (fn [t] (let [p (f/untuple t)] (tp/tuple (dec' (first p)) (second p))))))

(f/map (f/values (.rightOuterJoin rdd-idx-offset rdd-idx)) f/untuple)
```

Next you can map using similar approach as before.

**Edit**

Quick note [on using atoms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32209413/1560062). What is the problem there is lack of referential transparency and that you're leveraging incidental properties of a given implementation not a contract. There is nothing in the `map` semantics that requires elements to be processed in a given order. If internal implementation changes it may be no longer valid. Using Clojure

```
(defn foo [x] (let [aa @a] (swap! a (fn [&args] x)) aa))

(def a (atom 0))
(map foo (range 1 20))
```

compared to:

```
(def a (atom 0))
(pmap foo (range 1 20))
```

Comment: @Jyd I've added a short comment about atoms. I think you'll find it useful.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you put into this, I wasn't sure about the use of mutable data structures in clojure development, as advised, its no the way to go, if I mutate the data structure, just trying to avoid the use of mutable data especially now that I'm in my early clojure dev stage. or what will you advise?

Comment: a quick follow up, I've noticed that `["5" "16" ""] ["07" "" "36"] ["07" "" "34"]` will produce `["5" "16" ""] ["07" "16" "36"] ["07" "" "34"]` and not `["5" "16" ""] ["07" "16" "36"] ["07" "16" "34"]` as expected, except if of course we'd repeat the process again to fill in the blanks

Comment: It is possible to support arbitrary look-behind but it takes some effort. Instead of last element you should collect last-not-empty for broadcast. Then you have to correct it to handle partitions with all empty columns (shift last non empty value from the previous partition). Finally instead of partition + map you can use recursive function which will fill columns with last non-empty.